# What to do if OS X Facebook notifications are unreliable?

Tags: facebook, notifications

with the release of OS X 10.8.2, **Facebook notifications** have been introduced. But so far, I'm having problems with the reliability of those: they only appear randomly. Compared to the amount of Notification Center pop ups I *should* get, I estimate I only receive 10% of all notifications.

Is this the same for you?
Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Same here! And I can’t even choose what notifications I get.

Comment: Exactly same here, it's a feature which is not implemented in FB integration yet. You've to wait to work it properly. Try some other apps instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using http://glowforfb.com for two weeks now and haven't missed **one** notification since then :)!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The notifications appear to be the same as what would be seen in the iOS app. It picks up post from friends who are active and sends out a notification for their post. I have a few friends with high volume of post and these friends are a constant source of my notifications. Other than that I am unsure of how the notifications are handled.